# fallo al asignar valores a variables con punteros

Tags: punteros

## Problema con punteros

Le asigno valor a la primera variable utilizando un puntero, luego reutilizo   el mismo puntero y le asigno un valor a la siguiente variable pero   no entiendo porque la ultima imprime un valor que no tiene nada que ver con el codigo (==37)
querio saber porque pasa esto.

[image: codigo fuente]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stackoverflow, primeramente, el código no se muestra con imágenes sino que se pega aquí como texto y luego se le asigna, el formato de código cuando se hace click en las dobles llaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está acá:

```
*puntero=&var1;
```

En realidad, al declarar la variable de esta forma:

```
int *puntero=&var;
```

Es declarar a puntero como justamente, un apuntador hacia una dirección que en este caso será la de var, el error que cometes al hacer:

```
*puntero=&var1;
```

Puesto que puntero, ya es un apuntador, no necesitas poner el * otra vez.

Directamente, pones:

```
puntero=&var1;
```

Sino es como decir que el apuntador al contenido de puntero sea igual a la dirección de var1, pero como eso no está haciendo que puntero apunte a var1, se produce el error al tratar de cambiar el valor luego con:

```
 *puntero=4;
```

El número que te aparece en el printf es el resultado de una variable sin un valor, es como cuando te excedes en un vector de caracteres, el valor n+1 va a tener un símbolo raro y el siguiente y el siguiente, puesto que estás consultando lugares de la memoria completamente indiferentes a tu código(?